# SQL Server Table Valued Parameters

Tags: sql-server, table-valued-parameters

I am attempting to create a table valued parameter for input into an MS SQL Server stored proc.  My create statement:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.tvt_AbusedBy AS TABLE  
( Assessment_Behavorial_AbusedID int, Assessment_BehavorialID int,
  Ref_Abuse_TypeID int, Abuser_Name varchar(50), GenderID int,
  Relationship_TypeID int, Age int)
```

When attempting to add as a parameter into the proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[qryAddUpdateMultipletblAssessment_Behavorial_Abused] 
@prm_Assessment_Abused AS dbo.tvt_AbusedBy READONLY,
```

I get an error reading "The parameter @prm_Assessment_Abused cannot be declared READONLY since it is not a table valued parameter".

It does not seem to recognize it as a table valued parameter.

If I remote the READONLY stipulation, it gives me an error "Parameter or variable @prm_Assessment_Abused has an invalid type.

Must be an issue with how I am attempting to create the table valued parameter type.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try taking out `AS` in the parameter declaration.

Comment: remove dbo. from table value paramneter name

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `AS` when adding parameters in a stored procedure declaration:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[qryAddUpdateMultipletblAssessment_Behavorial_Abused] 
  @prm_Assessment_Abused dbo.tvt_AbusedBy READONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

From MS documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
You don't need AS before parameters, use it afters parameters declaration.

Example from link (a little edited):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_add_kitchen 
@dept_id int, @kitchen_count int NOT NULL  
AS  
BEGIN
  UPDATE dbo.Departments  
  SET kitchen_count = ISNULL(kitchen_count, 0) + @kitchen_count  
  WHERE id = @dept_id  
END;  
GO
```